# Flutter iOS App not running in Background

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm developing a Flutter Workout App that has a Timer/Player Feature. There is a "playing" state, where every second a tick sound is played and a "rest" state, with a countdown timer and sounds for the last 30, 20, 10 , 3, 2, 1 seconds.

I encounter the problem, that on iOS, when I lock the screen or open another app, the app seems to pause and my timers are not continuing. It works out of the app on android.

Is there a way to allow running a flutter app in the background on iOS? Whats the best solution for my problem?

Comment: Can you share what versions of iOS you have tried it? What devices?

Comment: I tried it on an old iPhone 6 Plus running iOS 12.4.3. Do you expect it to work on newer devices/versions?

Comment: You have to enable the apps background modes. On iOS is a bit different from Android, only certain types of apps are allowed to run in background, in order to mark your app as this kind of app you need to set it's capabilities. Be aware, if you set wrong capabilities, your app will be rejected.

Comment: @danypata I have set the `audio` UIBackgroundMode but it doesn't fix my issue, is that what you mean with background mode?